# How to transform cURL into Swift?

Tags: swift, api, http, request, nsurlsession

The curl API request that I am trying to transform into Swift:

```
curl \
  -F 'image=YOUR_IMAGE_URL' \
  -H 'api-key:quickstart-QUdJIGlzIGNvbWluZy4uLi4K' \
  https://api.deepai.org/api/deepdream
```

The code I've written so far:

```
import Cocoa

func postData(inputImageURL: String){

guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.deepai.org/api/deepdream"), let payload = inputImageURL.data(using: .utf8) else {return}
let boundary = generateBoundary()
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("quickstart-QUdJIGlzIGNvbWluZy4uLi4K", forHTTPHeaderField: "api-key")
request.httpBody = payload

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }
    
    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
    }
  }.resume()
}

func generateBoundary() -> String {
  return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}

postData(inputImageURL: "https://e1.365dm.com/20/07/768x432/skysports-manchester-united_5038422.jpg?20200713135539")
```

The output I want the console to print:

```
{
"id": "b063a127-55a9-4939-89c5-b98175d7d55d", 
"output_url": "https://api.deepai.org/job-view-file/b063a127-55a9-4939-89c5-b98175d7d55d/outputs/output.jpg"
}
```

This is the [website](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/deepdream) where the API documentation is. Is there a better way of interacting with the API. I would like to implement this into an App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here is what you can do to convert curl to SwiftCode

Step 1 : Open Postman

Step 2 : Click on import (Left top Corner / Cmd + O)

Step 3 : Click on Raw Text

Step 4 : Paste Your curl

Step 5 : Click on Continue and Then Import

Step 6 : Click on the imported Request

Step 7 : Under the Send Button You will find Button named code. Clicking on will show you a window where you can get the code for swift

You will get the swift code in URLSession with header params and etc